# Use query or where clause passed from the calling program

Tags: c++, oracle, crystal-reports

Can Crystal Reports use either a query or a where clause that is passed to it from the calling program?  (We're using C++ with Oracle.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. There are other ways to achieve the same behavior depending on your case. You can use standard CR parameters to change how records are filtered out after a query has been run.

Or if you wanted to get really fancy you could have your program run multiple variations on the same report, and have your calling program decide which one to run. Or your main subreport could be a shell report - a report that runs other reports based on a parameter you pass to it (and hides the rest.)